# unique_ptr push_back and std::list

Tags: c++

I was just wondering how would I be able to push back an object into a list with unique_ptr, if at all possible.

I am receiving the error:

```
  error: 
  no matching constructor for initialization of
  'std::__1::unique_ptr<tester::Stimulation,
  std::__1::default_delete<tester::Stimulation> >'
            ::new ((void*)__p) _Tp(__a0);
```

my code is as follow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

namespace tester
{
  class Stimulation
  {
    std::string name;

  public:
    Stimulation(std::string n) : name(n) {}
    std::string getName() const {return name;}
  };
}

using namespace tester;


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  std::list< std::unique_ptr<tester::Stimulation*> > configuration;
  //std::list< std::unique_ptr<tester::Stimulation> >::iterator i = configuration.begin();

  configuration.push_back(std::unique_ptr<tester::Stimulation>(new Stimulation("NAME1")));


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: I'm not sure, but your code looks ok to me. Please post the relevant error messages.

Comment: updated: error provided

Comment: @a-one Your code compiles just fine. Only an `#include<memory>` was to be added. See https://godbolt.org/g/XRL63t ... Was the missed header the problem?

Comment: just add #include<memory> and still receiving error: 
      no matching constructor for initialization of
      'std::__1::unique_ptr<tester::Stimulation,
      std::__1::default_delete<tester::Stimulation> >'
                ::new ((void*)__p) _Tp(__a0); @skypjack

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `new` for creating a new unique_ptr, but use `std::make_unique` (e.g., `std::make_unique<Stimulation>("NAME1")`).

I'd do

```
configuration.emplace_back("NAME1");
```

in order to not create an intermediate (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back; emplace_back creates a new object directly into the list, by calling the constructor).

Comment: so just use emplace_back and not declare the unique ptr in the list?

Comment: you can still use push_back but then you need to use std::make_unique. `emplace_back` directly calls the constructor of the `unique_ptr`.

Comment: no member named 'emplace_back' in
      'std::__1::list<std::__1::unique_ptr<tester::Stimulation,
      std::__1::default_delete<tester::Stimulation> >,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::unique_ptr<tester::Stimulation,
      std::__1::default_delete<tester::Stimulation> > > >'

Comment: ahh yes I added that but the emplace_back is not working

Comment: emplace_back requires C++11.

Comment: Does it work with `configuration.push_back(std::make_unique<tester::Stimulation>("NAME1"));`?

Comment: Have you tried to add an empty constructor? (could also be private)

Comment: just added an empty constructor still an error @MrTux